# convert numeric week of year to a date (yyyy-mm-dd) in hiveql

Tags: date, hive, calendar, hiveql, simpledateformat

It is easy enough to extract a week value from a date in hiveql:

```
select date_format('2020-10-18','w');
```

Is there a function for reversing this process: extracting the end date when provided a year and week number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get accurate date you need to provide also week day along with year and week number in a year.

```
select date_format('2020-10-18','w'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2020, 43, 7', 'yyyy, w, u'), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Returns:

```
43   2020-10-18
```

It looks like week number in a year counted from Sundays and day number in a week is counted from Mondays because Monday is 19th:

```
select date_format('2020-10-18','w u'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2020, 43, 1', 'yyyy, w, u'), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

returns

```
43  2020-10-19
```

If that is true, you can fix it by subtracting `60*60*24` from unix_timestamp:

```
select date_format('2020-10-18','w'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2020, 43, 1', 'yyyy, w, u')-60*60*24, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Returns:

```
43  2020-10-18
```

**UPDATE:** Surprisingly, if not providing day in a week, only year and week number, it works also counting Sunday as a week day by default but it will be not correct for other dates for example 2020-01-20, it will return the same Sunday 2020-01-18, check it yourself:

```
select date_format('2020-10-18','w'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2020, 43', 'yyyy, w'), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

returns:

```
43  2020-10-18
```

So, if you do not have day in a week and do not need absolutely accurate date, then use

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2020, 43', 'yyyy, w'), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Or like this (year and week number are selected from the table):

```
  select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(col_year, ', ', col_week), 'yyyy, w'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') from your_table;
```